# writing to a file mfc

Tags: c++, file, unicode, mfc

How to write unicode to a file using MFC. I tried writing to a file using Cfile class but not sure on how to specify length of TCHAR also having trouble printing out new lines. A code snippet is welcome.

Comment: Google search: "mfc write to file" gives loads of examples

Comment: `length_of_string * sizeof(TCHAR)`?

Comment: You should not be using TCHAR, because then the actual contents of the file will depend on compilation settings (thus, only your program will be able to work with the file - that's probably not what you want). Please refer to utf8everywhere.org about how to get correct platform-independent file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an automatic conversion of \n to \r\n characters use CStdioFile and the methods ReadString/WriteString. Following example uses CFile:

```
CString strFileContent;
CString strFilePath; 

CFile theFile(strFilePath, CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate);

// write BOM if you like
// WCHAR bom = 0xFEFF;
// theFile.Write(&bom, 2);

theFile.Write( (LPCTSTR) strFileContent, 
    strFileContent.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR));
```